# Multiple divs addClass and removeClass at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make these two divs always have opposite skew angles.
But it doesn’t work and when I click on body, then they have the same skewY value.
Does anyone know how to correct this? Thank you!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1 content skew1">
</div>
<div class="div2 content skew2">
</div>

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.skew1 {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.skew2 {
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

$(function () {
  $("body").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".content").hasClass("skew1")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("skew1").addClass("skew2");
    } else {
      $(".content").removeClass("skew2").addClass("skew1");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: maybe `... function() { $('.content').toggleClass('skew1').toggleClass('skew2') }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.removeClass` and `.addClass` both operate on ALL the elements in `.content`.  Which means after one click they will have exactly the same classes.  Use `.toggleClass` instead.

Exmaple:
When your App runs `$('.content')` will return `[ <div1 class="skew1">, <div2 class="skew2"> ]`
On the first click `.removeClass('skew1')` will return `[ <div1>, <div2 class="skew2"> ]`
Then, `.addClass('skew2')` will return `[ <div1 class="skew2">, <div2 class="skew2"> ]`

```js
$(function () {
  $("body").on("click", function () {
    $(".content").toggleClass("skew1 skew2");
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.skew1 {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.skew2 {
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1 content skew1">
</div>
<div class="div2 content skew2">
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than `$(".content").toggleClass("skew1").toggleClass("skew2");` you can do `$(".content").toggleClass("skew1 skew2");`

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").on("click", function() {
    const div1 = $(".div1");
    const div2 = $(".div2");
    if (div1.hasClass("skew1")) {
      div1.removeClass("skew1");
      div1.addClass("skew2");
      div2.removeClass("skew2");
      div2.addClass("skew1");
    } else {
      div1.removeClass("skew2");
      div1.addClass("skew1");
      div2.removeClass("skew1");
      div2.addClass("skew2");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `toggleClass`

```js
$(function () {
  $("body").on("click", function () {
    $('.content').toggleClass('skew1').toggleClass('skew2')
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.skew1 {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.skew2 {
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1 content skew1">
</div>
<div class="div2 content skew2">
</div>
```